# Combine SQL Queries?

Tags: sql

How can I combine the following SQL queries so that I get one output table containing the name of the state, city, and postal code in 3 separate columns on the same row? I have little experience with SQL, but making 3 separate queries if I could make just one seems a bit better to me.

```
SELECT City_tx FROM City WHERE City_id = 11

SELECT StateProv_tx FROM StateProv WHERE StateProv_id = 12

SELECT PostalCode_tx FROM PostalCode WHERE PostalCode_id = 13
```

Comment: can you show your table schema... normaly you would use a join but therefore the tables have to have any connection

Comment: it also would make sence ... as it is a 1 : 1 relation ... to put all this information into one single table ... city - state - postalCode ... normally they never change and none of them can have 2 or more of the other ones

Comment: The tables don't have anything in common with each other. I guess using `JOIN` is out?

Comment: Well join will work perfectly fine if you have some relation in all three tables. If you could post schema or ralation between these three table that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any relations between tables. Simply declare 3 variables & set them (just another method other than above answers);

```
DECLARE @City VARCHAR(100), @StateProv VARCHAR(100), @PostalCode VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @City = City_tx FROM City WHERE City_id = 11
SELECT @StateProv = StateProv_tx FROM StateProv WHERE StateProv_id = 12
SELECT @PostalCode = PostalCode_tx FROM PostalCode WHERE PostalCode_id = 13

SELECT @City City, @StateProv StateProv, @PostalCode PostalCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(City_tx),max(StateProv_tx),max(PostalCode_tx) from
(
SELECT City_tx ,'' StateProv_tx, '' PostalCode_tx FROM City WHERE City_id = 11
union all
SELECT '' City_tx ,StateProv_tx, '' PostalCode_tx  FROM StateProv WHERE StateProv_id = 12
union all
SELECT '' City_tx ,'' StateProv_tx, PostalCode_tx FROM PostalCode WHERE PostalCode_id = 13
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `City_id`, `StateProv_id` and `PostalCode_id` are all unique, then it's just a matter of using a cross join and only limiting on those fields. Might not be the most efficient, but not really any other good options if you have no other relations between the rest of the data:

```
SELECT City_tx, StateProv_tx, PostalCode_tx
FROM City, StateProv, PostalCode
WHERE City_id = 11 AND StateProv_id = 12 AND PostalCode_id = 13
```

Again though, barring the fact that we have no schema or any information on how the data is laid out, this might not even be able to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT City_tx, (SELECT StateProv_tx FROM StateProv WHERE StateProv_id = 12) as sp_tx, (SELECT PostalCode_tx FROM PostalCode WHERE PostalCode_id = 13) as pc_tx FROM City WHERE City_id = 11
```

It should work... at least in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

`Cross join` seems like a good approach, assuming that you have exactly one row returned in each case:

```
select *
from (SELECT City_tx FROM City WHERE City_id = 11) c cross join
     (SELECT StateProv_tx FROM StateProv WHERE StateProv_id = 12) s cross join
     (SELECT PostalCode_tx FROM PostalCode WHERE PostalCode_id = 13) p
```